# use css link with script gets encoded

Tags: javascript, html, css, reference

I am using a static server ip in my references to .js and .css, the .js files pick this up good however the .css files are being encoded

`<link href="http://<%=set_server()%>/css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />` gets `<link href="http://&lt;%=set_server()%>/css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />`.

Did anybody has this before and knows the solution how not to get encoded?

Comment: In HTML, those two bits of code are equivalent. Why is the encoding a problem?

Comment: the problem is that it wont load the stylesheets ))

Comment: Since they aren't valid URLs (you can't start a hostname with `<`), that isn't surprising - but not a consequence of the browser getting a URL encoded for HTML instead of one that isn't.

Comment: I suspect that what is happening is that you have some unspecified server side environment which is supposed to process `<%=stuff%>` and isn't. Then the browser is trying to process the server side code. But you haven't told us anything about whatever is supposed to process the  `<%=stuff%>`

Comment: well it gets encode by html I dont do this within the .js it works good, off course it looks for the url http://&lt;%=set_server(), but I want it to avoid to encode the <%

Comment: I am using this <script src="http://<%=set_server()%>/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="http://<%=set_server()%>/css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />, the .js is not being encoded however the link does, so wonder why this is like this

Comment: If you do this on -1 means you think its a stupid question, however do you know the answer, how to avoid that it gets encoded?

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend not using inline code in a href path. If you change it to `<link href="/css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />` that should work (note the leading slash, that will go to the root directory of your site).

If you *really* need to use the inline code to build the URL for some reason, you should probably just build the whole link tag in the code (so you would just have a call to your function and that builds a proper link tag).

Comment: Why the downvote? It's a proper answer (at least the first half is)